# What registers am I to push and pop when calling a function?

Tags: assembly, masm

Consider the following code:

```
ArraySum PROC 
; Receives: ESI points to an array of doublewords, 
; ECX = number of array elements. 
; Returns: EAX = sum 
;----------------------------------------------------- 
    push esi ; save ESI, ECX 
    push ecx 
    mov eax,0 ; set the sum to zero 

L1:
    add eax,[esi] ; add each integer to sum 
    add esi,4 ; point to next integer 
    loop L1 ; repeat for array size 
    pop ecx ; restore ECX, ESI 
    pop esi 
    ret 
ArraySum ENDP
```

Why did the coder decided to save the values of `ESI` and `ECX`?
I mean, the one which calls `ArraySum` from somewhere must 'prepare' both `ESI` and `ECX` for `ArraySum`.

Less specific, what registers should I save when writing a function? Just the ones I use without anyone from outside the function knowing it, or all of the registers I use except the ones which are used to return values?

Comment: This is platform-specific, but on 32-bit Windows, and I believe on Linux as well, a routine can trash `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx` but must preserve all other register values.

Comment: There are far too many "standards" in x86 to reliably pick one.  Lots of tool vendors around 20 years ago.  You have to consult the docs of whatever compiler you interop with.  This is an old one btw, nobody generates LOOP anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant, is it possible that the standard in the text I'm reading (which the code is taken from) is that the coder must preserve all general registers expect of the return values?

Comment: There's no way to tell if you can't be more explicit.  It is never the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 32-bit x86 code, the *callee-saved* registers (i.e. the ones functions should preserve) are  `EDI`, `ESI`, `EBP`, and `EBX`. The function you've shown modifies `ESI` inside the loop and therefore needs to save its original value and restore it before returning.

`ECX` is among the *caller-saved* registers (i.e. it's up the the callers of the function to preserve its value if it needs it), so it's unclear why the function you've shown saves it. Perhaps the coder made up his/her own calling convention.

See table 4 in [Agner Fog's "Calling conventions" document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

Comment: The loop instruction modifies ECX (as do loopz, loopnz, and jcxz). ECX is the Count register, and a few other instructions modify it as well.

Comment: @Fred: Sure. My point was that it's unclear why the function preserves the original value of `ECX` since it isn't required to (as per `stdcall` or `cdecl` on IA-32).

Comment: @Michael, I don't have the full code, I just saw this function and wondered the exact same thing.